# Filtered by a custom field, ordered by another

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, order

I am trying to loop custom post-types, filtered by a custom field `artist-status => invited`
and ordered by another custom field `last-name` alphabetically. Here is what I managed to write, and it doesn’t work as I need:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'artist',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'artist-status',
    'meta_value' => 'invited'
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array (
         array( 'key' => 'last-name')
       )
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sorting it incorrectly. You will need to check for `artist-status` meta key with `meta_query` and sort by `last-name` metakey.

Here is your query.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'artist',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'last-name',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array (
        array(
            'key' => 'artist-status',
            'value' => 'invited',
            'compare' => '=',
        )
    )
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) this snippet could be useful for you case:

Display posts of type 'my_custom_post_type', ordered by 'age', and filtered to show only ages 3 and 4 (using meta_query)

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'my_custom_post_type',
    'meta_key'   => 'age',
    'orderby'    => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'age',
            'value'   => array( 3, 4 ),
            'compare' => 'IN',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: All the examples I find deals with a `compare` key. I don’t have that comparison to do. That is my problem.

Comment: You can change the code to adapt for you needs.